# Consulta sobre el funcionamiento del Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Muy buenas tardes colegas programadores (testers) ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar una entrada de un valor del tipo  css=.modality-button:nth-child(2) .balance-amount por un identificador estático para que lo reconozca Selenium al realizar mis pruebas automatizadas?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a cómo conseguir una referencia al elemento? Puedes usar un selector CSS y el exactamente cómo depende del lenguaje. Así que mejora tu pregunta si quieres una respuesta más acertada.

Comment: Si para ser más exacto pasa lo siguiente, tengo este elemento HTML (botón) <span class="mat-button-wrapper">Empezar Impulse Challenge</span> , al grabar mi prueba en Selenium llega a ese punto y se detiene la prueba porque no reconoce el click que le doy al elemento.

Comment: Por favor haz click en [edit] para agregar más detalles. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example]

Comment: Si tú has hecho el desarrollo, ¿por qué no pones un ID al no _botón_ y lo referencias por ese ID? Me parece lo más sencillo.